# multicast local scope in plain english

Tags: multicast

Please some explain this in plain English;

RFC2365 says:
239.255.0.0/16 is defined to be the IPv4 Local Scope.  The Local
   Scope is the minimal enclosing scope, and hence is not further
   divisible. Although the exact extent of a Local Scope is site
   dependent, locally scoped regions must obey certain topological
   constraints. In particular, a Local Scope must not span any other
   scope boundary. Further, a Local Scope must be completely contained
   within or equal to any larger scope. In the event that scope regions
   overlap in area, the area of overlap must be in its own local scope.
   This implies that any scope boundary is also a boundary for the Local
   Scope. The more general topological requirements for administratively
   scoped regions are discussed below.

what is "overlap scoping"?

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: And the term "overlap scoping" does not appear in the extract you cited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, a Local Scope is a limited number of devices which share the same physical space. Now, each Local Scope must obey to the boundary priciple which states that each physical space needs to correspond accurately to meaningful spaces as they are normally defined. To give an example, a laptop is to discover a service such as a printer in a hotel room, it must find a printer in the same room as the laptop and not in the room next door.

What the last part is saying is, if you have a look at the venn diagram I attached, if the Local Scope is the overlaped area between Scope 1 and Scope 2 then the physical properties of Scope 1 and/or Scope 2 will be included in the scope of the Local Scope.

[image: Venn Diagram of Scopes]